# How to run repeated process while application is in background in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, nstimer

In my application i have one function updatetimer which updates timer continuously.I want this process to remain continue while application is in background.but that method is getting called only when application is in foreground.its not getting called while application is in background.Below is the code for that.How can i fix this?

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 


                         timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
                        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

                        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; 
                    });
```

Comment: You don't have the only app on the user's device.  You have to share (see the answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the apple docs, only these tasks are allowed to run in the background, and they each have their own limitations:

> audio—The app plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)
>
> location—The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.
>
> voip—The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls
> using an Internet connection.
>
> newsstand-content—The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and
> processes magazine or newspaper content in the background.
>
> external-accessory—The app works with a hardware accessory that needs
> to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the External
> Accessory framework.
>
> bluetooth-central—The app works with a Bluetooth accessory that needs
> to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the CoreBluetooth
> framework.

otherwise you can ask for up to 10 min. of extra run-time with this: (also from apple docs)

```
bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
 
    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 
        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.
 
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
```

for more information:
[Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)